# Why Need to set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable separately when I have been authenticated with service account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, service-accounts

I am being confused with this authentication method a lot.
I have a service account which has all the required roles and permissions for me to interact with GCP services. I have activated the service account using "gcloud auth activate-service-account" command and selected the right project and service account using "gcloud init". But still, I am not not able to interact with GCP services. I have to set an environment variable "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS" with the correct json key file and then only I am able to interact with GCP services.

My question is if my service account has all the permissions and my current active service account is also the same why I need to set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS. How gcloud authentication is working internally?

Comment: Can you also specify what gcloud commands are you trying to run and what error message do you get?

Comment: please specify what command are you trying to use, or if this is happening to you when using a client library which one are you using?

Comment: I am using a python script, which is having python API's mainly to interact with PubSub and bigquery.

Answer (score 1):

The Google Cloud SDK CLI `gcloud` has its own authentication structure (files and databases). This structure is not made available to your applications running on the same system.

For developers, using the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` is part of the SDK client functions for locating credentials. This is called ADC (Application Default Credentials). The SDK clients will search for credentials.

[Google Cloud Application Default Credentials](https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-application-default-credentials/)

If you are interested in learning the secrets of where the SDK stores credentials:

[Google Cloud – Where are my credentials stored](https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-where-are-my-credentials-stored/)

Answer (score 0):

Google's SDKs permit authentication to be handled by Application Default Credentials (ADCs). Apart from simplifying your code, ADCs provide some portability  because code will run unchanged locally, and on Google compute services. This is because ADCs automatically search for credentials, either in `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` or from metadata.

When you use `gcloud auth application-default` to set a service account. You're setting the service account for the `gcloud` command(s) but **not** for code that you run on the same client. This code does not check the `gcloud` configuration for credentials. It looks for `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` absent a local metadata service.

See: [Authenticating as a Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#automatically). There used to be a better document describing this.

@john-hanley beat me to it.